# Elasticsearch completion suggester phrase instead of terms

Tags: mysql, jdbc, elasticsearch, autocomplete

I am developing a search engine with Elasticsearch 1.6 and it's all working great. I get the data from my MySQL database with the JDBC importer from Jorg Prante. I would like to use the Elasticsearch complete suggester like documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html). The problem is only that I cannot find out how to do this without having tags like shwown in the examples everywhere. I only have the title of a product which is a quite long title.

So I would like to know how to make this work like expected by using the full phrase of the title or otherwise how to split the titlephrase into tags and adding them.

This is my current mapping for the field 'title' but that does only return a (not very relevant) whole phrase.

```
  curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/jdbc/" -d'
{
   "mappings": {
      "jdbc": {
         "properties": {
            "title": {
               "type": "completion",
               "index_analyzer": "simple",
               "search_analyzer": "simple",
               "payloads": true
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Comment: can u show a little of it here so peeps dont have to jump around, plus a little of what you did

Comment: I don't understand. "This is my current mapping for the field 'title' but that does only return a (not very relevant) whole phrase." what do you expect? Give some examples of titles, what you want to search for, what is the expectation and what you get now!

Comment: @Sgards by providing your current mapping, you suggest it needs improvement, but from the linked documentation, I conclude the solution is probably in different indexing. If this conclusion is correct, the question is misleading and can be improved by adding your current indexing.